# Is there an equivalent of the Reachability class for Actionscript 3?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, reachability

In iOS dev it is common practice to use the Reachability class to check that you can hit a web service or other network path. I need to do something similar to check that an asset path that is being passed into a Flash SWF exists.

I don't want to run a test to load a transparent image cause this will take time to return a fault or result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ServiceMonitor.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/common/langref/air/net/ServiceMonitor.html

http://code.google.com/p/poliwar/source/browse/trunk/projeto/servidor/lib/air2b2/?r=66